# Computer freezes during hibernate

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, hibernate

For the last 2 days, if i get my latop to hibernate, it gets to the screen where it says 'Preparing to hibernate' and then it stays there, nothing happens. I had to take out the power cord, and it stayed on that screen till the battery ran out. How can I fix this?

It has been hibernating fine for several months before this.

I'm using win xp.

Comment: How much free space is there on the drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it may be laptop don't have enough memory to do the hybernation in windows drive....else try to disable the hybernate option and restart.....then enable again and try..........

Comment: thanks, I think that was indeed the problem, if i close all running programs when i hibernate then it works fine now

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [this Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907477) article entitled *"How to troubleshoot hibernation and standby issues in Windows XP"*. I've not read much myself, but had a quick glance and it contains various suggestions that cover various possibilities - although it seems mostly aimed at problems coming out of hibernation rather than entering it, they may well be helpful anyway.

---

Has anything *changed* on your laptop recently? For example:

- Do you have any new peripherals attached (even innocuous seeming ones, like say a mouse)?
- Or any new software installed?
- Potentially a recently updated device driver?

It could be something in these sort of categories is somehow obstructing the hibernation process - in which case try unplugging anything new, stop or (temporarily) uninstall any new programs, and/or try a system restore to before when the problem started.

If these activities stop the problem, you will then have to play the trial-and-error game by reconnecting devices and reinstalling software on at a time until you find out what is causing the problem.